AWS RDS SQL Server is not accessible through internet
I've setup AWS RDS SQL Server database (2022) and am trying to access it through SSMS 20.2.
It keeps throwing this error:

Cannot connect to database-2.abcdfghi.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com.
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider)
Error Number: 53
Severity: 20
State: 0
Program Location:
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action1 wrapCloseInAction)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, Boolean useOriginalAddressInfo, Boolean disableTnir)   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover, Boolean isFirstTransparentAttempt, Boolean disableTnir) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, ServerCertificateValidationCallback serverCallback, ClientCertificateRetrievalCallback clientCallback, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, SqlClientOriginalNetworkAddressInfo originalNetworkAddressInfo, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource1 retry) at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateSqlConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IDbConnection dbConnection, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer.ObjectExplorerService.ValidateConnection(UIConnectionInfo ci, IServerType server)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.ConnectionDlg.Connector.ConnectionThreadUser()
The network path was not found

I also made sure to allow public access and set required inbound rules


Most/all internet articles seems to suggest these as solutions, but it doesn't seem to solve mine, any ideas where should I look ?

Does your security group have the default outbound rules and do your subnets have the default network ACLs for both inbound and outbound, or did you modify any of them?

...there is so much wrong with this. Before you read any further, consider a more correct solution: hosting the DB in a private subnet and establishing a VPN tunnel to the VPC.
However, if you must access this instance from public internet, here's a checklist for you:

Is the instance Available?
Is the subnet Public?
Is the DB instance Publicly accessible?
Does one of the Security Groups allow connections to the DB?
If you telnet into the port, do you get a connection and a prompt of some sort?
Can you log in with a generic SQL client?

To test, I would suggest setting up an instance (Linux) on the same subnet as the RDS server and connecting to said instance using aws ssm start-session. Make sure you assign this instance a role that allows it to run an SSM agent.
